# Vimeo advanced api videos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, video, vimeo

I have a web app built on Rails using the Vimeo gem. I need to get every video for 1 particular user. The simple API puts a cap at 20 videos, but it has better information that the advanced API, at least for my use case (video_url, thumbnail). This means that I need to ping their server once to get all videos, and then 1 time for each video to get the necessary information. This seems incredibly excessive.

1) Is there a way to get the information I need with 1 request?
2) Is there any possible way to get more than 20 videos from the simple API?
3) Has anyone ever had any luck with Vimeo's customer service?

Here's the gem for reference, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything other than acting as an API wrapper. I expect the data I'm getting is correct. 
[vimeo gem](http://github.com/matthooks/vimeo/tree/master)

Answer (score 2):

*2) Is there any possible way to get more than 20 videos from the simple API?*

If you add ?page= to your request url, the simple API allows you to request up to page 3 (starting with page 1), with a max of 20 videos per page.

For example: http://vimeo.com/api/v2/username/videos.json?page=2

Would return videos 21-40 created by the specific user, assuming the user has created that many videos.

With 3 calls, you can get a max total of 60 videos. Not positive this meets your requirements, but it's one way to get more videos from Vimeo's Simple API.

Comment: Thanks for this. Not the exact answer I was looking for, but definitely solved my problem. Just implementing an infinite scroll fetching the next page.